# Error: Too many command line arguments Expected at most one positional argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, bitbucket, terraform-provider-aws, hashicorp

I am getting the below Error when trying to execute terraform in BitBucket Pipeline. However, the same code works perfectly fine when `$parent_ou_id == "r-plat"` and fails for anything else with below Error. Can someone take a look? TIA

```
          - terraform init
          - if [[  $parent_ou_id == "r-plat" ]]; then AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$TEST_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$TEST_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" ; fi
          # Automatically apply
          - >
            terraform apply
            --auto-approve
            -var account_id=$account_id
            -var app_id=$app_id
            -var customer_name="$customer_name"
            -var environment=$non_prod_environment_name
            -var env_id=$non_prod_env_id
            -var parent_id=$parent_ou_id
            -var billing_id=$billing_id
            -var builder=$builder
            -var cloudcraft=$cloudcraft
            -var enterprise_support=$enterprise_support
            -var category=$category
            -var owner=$owner
            -var budget_daily=$budget_daily
            -var aws_region=us-east-1 # Even though this is global (AWS), a region specification is needed here.
          - aws_account_id=$(terraform output aws_account_id | grep -o '[0-9]\{12\}')
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: Did you try with quotations: `parent_id="${parent_ou_id}"`?

Comment: Same issue - with `parent_id="${parent_ou_id}"`

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this using quotes for :

```
 -var owner="$owner"
 -var budget_daily="$budget_daily"
```